# Running total Balance column in C# DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

Balance column coming from database... But when i enter the same Pkt No. in Pkt No. column in any row so the balance value will change.

```
Pkt No    Balance    Item Code    Weight
323-12    10         11001          3 
323-12    7          11002          3
323-12    4          11003          4
```

Comment: are you developing application in WPF? Windows Forms ? or ASP.NET ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WPF..this might be helpful

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/02/how-to-display-sum-of-columns-total-in.html

Comment: I am not using wpf & also its not helpful for me.. but thnx